# Custom share modal for sharing into Android app

Tags: android

How do you create a custom modal layout for sharing data into an application? For example, if you are on a page in Chrome and try and share into Facebook, the Facebook share modal pops up and lets you edit the data that gets passed into Facebook. The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html) only cover the simple use case of launching an activity within the application and passing in the data. However, I don't want to launch the activity; I want this to be a separate modal altogether that just functions as an overlaid form and sends it to a backend much like Facebook's share function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I don't want to launch the activity

Sharing is only done via activities.

> I want this to be a separate modal altogether that just functions as an overlaid form and sends it to a backend much like Facebook's share function.

Then create a separate dialog-themed activity that has your `ACTION_SEND` `<intent-filter>`. That dialog-themed activity can collect information from the user, then forward that along to whatever inside of your app.

Comment: Do you have any resources for creating a dialog themed activity?

Comment: @JCDJulian: Create a custom theme that is based on an existing dialog theme (e.g., `Theme.Material.Dialog`) and ties in with the rest of your app's theme. So, for example, if you are using `appcompat-v7` and `Theme.AppCompat`, you would use `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` or something. Mostly what it does is say that your activity's window is `wrap_content`/`wrap_content` with respect to your content view, as opposed to filling the available screen space.